# Bad kerning when using -[NSString drawInRect: withAttributes:]

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-text

When using -[NSString drawInRect:withAttributes:], mainly when using the built-in Helvetica Neue but also with other fonts, the kerning is really bad. However, when the same string is rendered in Text Edit (which uses NSTextView) the kerning is great. Consider these two strings:

[image: Bad kerning]

[image: Good kerning]

For small point sizes, the first case (rendered in Cocoa) is nearly illegible, while the second case (from Text Edit) is much better. I don't think that kerning information is being used at all here. If I apply the NSKernAttribute with a value of 0.0 (which according to the documentation turns off kerning) I get the same result, the one at the top.

I also tried using Core Text with CTLineDraw, but still got the bad kerning. So my question is, is there anything special I need to do to enable kerning in the Cocoa text system? If not, how does NSTextView apply kerning?

Comment: What OS are you running? There is no difference on my 10.7.4. I do see 2-pixel difference on 10.6.8 for 72pt H.Neue, but that is still a lot lower than on your screenshot. Are your sure the default typing attributes in your NSTextView don't already include some value, did you try sending it `useStandardKerning:`?

Comment: This is 10.7.4, with the standard Helvetica Neue (version 7.0d27e1). The second screenshot is from Text Edit (the app), using a fresh document.

Comment: Select All, Format, Font, Kern, Use Default/None — does it change anything? I don't have that difference between TextEdit and custom-drawn attributed string. What about NSTextFieldCell and NSButtonCell, do they draw bad too for you?

Comment: Use Default / None does not change the appearance in Text Edit at all. NSTextFieldCell is bad too. However, when I tried this on 10.8 everything looks great. Taking the Helvetica Neue version from 10.8 and putting into 10.7 didn't help though. I will try this on a few other 10.7 systems to see if I can reproduce it there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The top example is 'tighter' and the bottom one is 'looser'  see `-[NSTextView tightenKerning]`, `-[NSTextView loosenKerning]`. Here Apple is confusingly referring to what everyone else calls 'Tracking' as 'Kerning' ie. a constant amount of additional space (positive or negative) uniformly applied between each glyph, after the 'character advance' specified in the font, to make text appear, well, tighter or looser.

The default 'tightness' or 'looseness' is a property of the rendering engine, not the font, and could easily be different between different OSX versions, apps or UI elements.

In a font, the kerning table is for adjustments to the character advance needed by specific pairs of glyphs, eg, in my hypothetical font: 'AV' is listed as a kerning pair - the 'A' should have a smaller advance when the character following it is a 'V'.

The OSX fonts Helvetica and HelveticaNeue (and many of the other fonts) have no kerning information at all, so you are right that no kerning information is being used in your examples.

If the font has no Kerning info, your question "How do i enable kerning in the Cocoa text system?" doesn't make sense or doesn't mean what you think it means (?).

Comment: Looking at the 'kern' table in the actual font, Helvetica Neue does include a kerning table with 98 kerning pairs. What makes you say it doesn't?

Comment: You're right, it does have some. I'm surprised and certain it didn't used to have any. Still, not any relevant to the example given though, right? i.e. - no pairs containing numerals

Comment: Yes, and most pairs are only negative adjustments. So, you're probably right, it is the tracking that is different. I do wonder why the default tracking is so different between 10.7 and 10.8. My solution for this is to leave the output looking "cramped" for 10.7 users, and instruct those bothered by it to upgrade to 10.8.